# When I implement database mirroring in SQL server it shows an error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, mirroring

[image: Error while starting mirroring]
When I click the start mirroring button it shows the below error message. When I try to connect the mirror and witness server through management studio it's connecting and working fine. The user I am logging to the machine is with the domain user.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337361.aspx

Comment: Make sure that the name and port of the mirror server instance are correct.

Comment: i check with ssms(by putting the port number) its connecting

Comment: Have you check out mirror server instance name  are correct or not.

Comment: Yes, checked that too

Comment: ,Have you verify or not both Principal and mirror server has started or not. SELECT state_desc
FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints;

Comment: ,you also verify your role on both server , is it same or not . SELECT role 
FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints;

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to verify the service accounts you are using:

- SQL Server service account requires CONNECT permissions to partners’
  endpoints
- Best option is to use domain accounts for all partners
- If using Local Service or Local System, must use certificate
  authentication.

> Ensure that the start date of the certificate is the current date or a
>   day in the past relative to all servers. Due to time zone differences,
>   if the current date on the server is earlier than the start date of
>   the certificate, endpoint authentication will fail. Set the START_DATE
>   option of the certificate to the day prior to when you are creating it
>   to ensure it will work in all time zones.

- If using Network Service, must use the computer account
  (domain\Computer$) Windows permissions are irrelevant. Do NOT add to 
  local admins group
- Check the SQL log for errors

Also check for  SQL Server service account in case it  do not exist in logins on both Principal & Mirror

You can fix for above case by adding the service account in logins on both the servers and grant the connect permission as below;

```
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::Mirroring TO [domain\loginname]
```

For further troubleshooting in case above does not help [read here](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/troubleshooting-atabasemirroringerror1418)